# Executor Service is not performing every job?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream, future, executorservice

I have a for-loop in my code which is executing a task for 1000 times. I want to reduce its execution time so I am trying to run it parallelly via executor service or streams. When I am performing these tasks via executor service(or streams) on around 1000 aggregates, I am only able to do around 950 jobs. Each job creates a directory and some files in it. Executor service implementation looks like this.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8); 
    List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
         for (String aggr : aggregates) {
              Future<?> future = executor.submit(() -> {  
                      //some generation task to be done for each aggregate
              });
         futures.add(future);
   }
   try {
        for (Future<?> fut : futures) {
            fut.get();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    executor.shutdown();
```

and Streams implementation looks like this.

```
aggregates.parallelStream().parallel().forEach(aggr ->{
       //some generation task to be done for each aggregate
});
```

In both the cases, it is missing around 50 jobs.
However, when I run sequentially like this it is not missing any jobs.

```
aggregates.parallelStream().sequential().forEach(aggr ->{
       //some generation task to be done for each aggregate
});
```

Why is it skipping some jobs? And how can I do all jobs in parallel. My system has 8 cores & i7 processor.

Comment: @user2449952: How did you solve similar kind of problem?

Comment: I have filled your template with some trivial task, and it executed all 1000 tasks just fine. Can you provide a bit more detail about what your are doing in your threads?

Comment: @MalteHartwig : task is to call JCodeModel based classes which create Java projects for each aggregate. So in total 1000 Java projects should be created.

Comment: @MalteHartwig : Also, tasks are moderately memory intensive.

Comment: Hmm, hard for us to reproduce. Could there be exceptions that you do not see? Maybe you can enable some kind of logging to see which tasks are executed. By the way, how do you know that it misses 50 jobs: are they never even scheduled/run, or do they just not produce your desired output? Last, as a hint for debugging, maybe you can create your own small sub class of ExecutorService to have some logging.

Comment: @MalteHartwig I am using logger and it catches every error it produces. Regarding the number of missing jobs, when I run sequentially it produces 1000 projects but when I do it parallelly, it produces roughly 50 fewer projects. Maybe the amount of work done is too high for each job, so it is missing some jobs?